# How to modify a collection deserialiser so that it produces a collection filtered out by given conditions?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

### DOMAIN

There is a class `Link`

```
public final class Link implements Serializable {

  private final String     _title;
  private final String     _href;
  private final List<Link> _links;

}
```

and there is a class `LinkDeserialiser` to deserialise `Link` objects from JSON

```
public final class LinkDeserialiser extends JsonDeserializer<Link> {

  @Override
  public Link deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
    final JsonNode node = context.readValue(parser, JsonNode.class);
    return Link.builder()
          .title(node.path(Constants.TITLE).asText().trim())
          .href(node.path(Constants.HREF).asText().trim())
          .links(loadLinks(node.path(Constants.LINKS)))
        .build();
  }

}
```

### PROBLEM

Before the `LinkDeserialiser`, we had a method

```
  public static List<Link> readLinks(JsonNode node) {
      List<Link> links = new ArrayList<>();
      node.forEach(childNode -> {
        Link link = new Link(childNode);
        if (link.valid()) {
          links.add(link);
        }
      });
      return links;
  }
```

that had parsed a `JsonNode` into a `List<Link>` and filtered that list by link validity. When we introduced the `LinkDeserialiser`, we found a proper way to deserialise `Link`s, which is

```
nodeParser.readValueAs(new TypeReference<List<Link>>() {});
```

The problem is, though, we don't know where to put the filter `link -> link.valid()` now. The `nodeParser` would populate the list with both valid and invalid `Link`s.

I'd rather not write a `JsonDeserializer<Collection<Link>>`, which seems like a dull idea.

### QUESTION

I'd love to get an answer to any of these questions:

1) How to modify a collection deserialiser so that it produces a collection filtered out by given conditions?

2) Is there any way to make a collection deserialiser "exception-tolerant" so when an exception is thrown, it keeps collecting objects into a collection? (an exception would be a kind of a filter)

### UPDATE 1

Link#valid is a fundamental rule and should be followed regardless of context and caller. I don't want (and can't) force the caller to filter the obtained collection by my (private) rules.

### UPDATE 2

From the sources of `CollectionDeserializer`

```
Object value;
if (t == JsonToken.VALUE_NULL) {
    if (_skipNullValues) {
        continue;
    }
    value = _nullProvider.getNullValue(ctxt);
} else if (typeDeser == null) {
    value = valueDes.deserialize(p, ctxt);
} else {
    value = valueDes.deserializeWithType(p, ctxt, typeDeser);
}
result.add(value);
```

it seems a deserialised `value` is added regardless of any conditions. I am considering extending the class and filter a resulting collection on my own.

Comment: Sorry, what is nodeParser?

Comment: @dai it's a `JsonParser` obtained by `codec.treeAsTokens(node)` to parse a particular node within a large JSON schema

Answer (score 0):

Short and uncomplicated: Parse all entries and remove the invalid ones.

```
nodeParser.readValueAs(new TypeReference<List<Link>>() {})
    .removeIf((Link link) -> !link.valid());
```

Comment: Thank you. However, `Link#valid` is a fundamental rule, and should be followed regardless of context and caller. I don't want (and can't) force the caller to filter out the obtained collection by my (private) rules.